# SELECT not working only inside @sql statement

Tags: mysql

i've got a query that works perfectly on a table, and doesn't work on another:
Here's the code (please note that is part of another query):

```
SET @sql = Null;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN columnA = "'  ,columnA, ' "THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS "'  ,columnA, ' "'))
into @sql
from table;
```

I don't know why it works for a table, but when i switch on another table it gives me this error

```
1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1260 Row 12 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()
```

IF i remove the @sql thing and i do the select it gives me the data without error...BUT it truncates the string at some point... i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are trying to build a dynamic query (prepared statement) which should be something like below. Again you `CASE` condition `CASE WHEN columnA = columnA THEN 1 ELSE 0 end` doesn't seems valid since `columnA = columnA` will always be true.

```
declare @sql varchar(200);
set @sql = 'SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(SUM(CASE WHEN columnA = columnA THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS columnA))
into (another sql query part)
from table';
```

Comment: Hey, as you can see, columnA is dynamic so your statement is not true. This code works perfectly but the group_concat() is limited and i get the error on some tables.

Answer (score 0):

`group_concat()` has a maximum length, and you seem to be exceeding that.  This is documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).

You can reset the maximum length.

But, you can also simplify your logic:

```
SET @sql = Null;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT REPLACE('SUM(ColumnA = ''@val'') as `@val`',
                                     '@val', columnA))
into @sql
from table;
```

Without the `case` expression, perhaps your string will fit in the default length.

I find it much easier to use `replace()` for constructing strings rather than `concat()`.  You can see the template that you are using.

Comment: i'm out of the maximun length of group_concat(), you're right. But your code above gives me problems, i can't figure out how to adjust the part after replace...can you help me?